# Kafka Streams: How bad is it to have side effects in filter, map?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, side-effects

If it depends, what side effects are OK and which are definitely BAD?

My situation is that it feels more natural to filter out some events and log them and increment a metric (an HTTP call) in a single function passed to filter. However, the documentation mentions to put side effects such as logging in peek and foreach, but doesn't mention why.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason against any external API calls is that many Streams API methods are time sensitive. If you do too much work, then the consumer group within the topology will fail to heartbeat and cause a rebalance, thereby halting the data flow. Even peek/foreach require an internal consumer and can have the same problem

That being said, HTTP / DB calls without a *short client timeout* can be bad. Logging or interfacing with local system resources is good.

If you really need external TCP/UDP calls, then stream/branch the data to some output topic, then use Kafka Connect for that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the timing considerations that @OneCricketeer mentioned, you may want to consider if you are using exactly-once semantics (EOS) or at-least-once semantics (ALOS).

With EOS, the side effect would happen once per record; whereas, with ALOS, there's a chance that a given record may be processed multiple times.

You can read more about that here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#semantics

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/concepts.html#processing-guarantees